# Is the repeat() function compatible with `grid` and `grid-template`?

Tags: css, css-grid, shorthand

When implementing either the css property `grid` or `grid-template` in combination with the `repeat()` function to declare the size of the columns, the property value seems to be incorrect.

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid: "header header" 2fr "aside main" 7fr "footer footer" 1fr / repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: red;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: blue;
}

.aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: black;
}

.container2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid: "header header" 2fr "aside main" 7fr "footer footer" 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
}

.header2 {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: red;
}

.main2 {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: blue;
}

.aside2 {
  grid-area: aside;
  background-color: green;
}

.footer2 {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="aside"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container2">
    <div class="header2"></div>
    <div class="main2"></div>
    <div class="aside2"></div>
    <div class="footer2"></div>
  </div>
  </div
```

As you can see in the previous snippet, I have used both the `repeat(2, 1fr)` function in one container, as well as used the longhand form of `1fr 1fr`. The first one reports the property value as erroneous, whilst the second one works.

This should not be the case as they are two ways of stating the same.

Comment: `1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr` is equal to `repeat(4,1fr)`

Comment: also the after `/` defines the columns not the rows

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's the issue, even though they're equal, repeat(4,1fr) doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: make a full working code so we can verify